# Separate text elements by comma into different variables in Python

Tags: string, split

I have a dataset like

```
Store    Products       
001     ['Skettles','M&M Candies', 'Dove Chocolates']
002     ['Danimals yogurt', 'Noosa', 'Graham Crackers','Dove Chocolates']
```

I hope to separate the different elements of products to different variables, like

```
Store    Product1         Product2    Product3          Product4
001      Skettles         M&M Candies Dove Chocolates
002      Danimals yogurt  Noosa       Graham Crackers   Dove Chocolates
```

How can I do that?

I tried the str.split() but it didn't work as how I expected.

Answer (score 0):

If the values under column `Products` are of type string, apply `ast.literal_eval` on them (skip this step if they are type `list`):

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Store": store, **{f"Product{i}": v for i, v in enumerate(lst, 1)}}
        for store, lst in zip(df["Store"], df["Products"].apply(literal_eval))
    ]
).fillna("")

print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   Store         Product1     Product2         Product3         Product4
0      1         Skettles  M&M Candies  Dove Chocolates                 
1      2  Danimals yogurt        Noosa  Graham Crackers  Dove Chocolates
```